# How to search ALL of column_A for a the FIRST value in column_B , and remove that row if no match is found. Using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to loop through my data such that the first value in column A is checked against all values in column B, and upon not returning a match, is deleted. I need this because I need a cascading effect, ie: removing one row will remove the unwanted value from column B, and will not give a "false positive" later in the loop.

Here is what I've got, but since it doesn't delete the unwanted rows, it's killing me.

```
df['Column_A'] = 100, 200, 200, 300, 300, 400, 410, 500, 500, 510, 510

df['Column_B'] = 300, 300, 300, 400, 400, 410, 510, 1100,1100,1010,1010

keep = df.loc[df["Column_A"].isin(df["Column_B"])]
```

Comment: Whats wrong with your current solution?

Comment: It doesn’t remove rows as they fail the criteria, which is essential to that cascade effect I need. So I would actually like to .inplace update the data frame removing as I go, but haven’t gotten it work right yet.

Comment: Can you provide expected output example along with input?

Comment: This was probably a poor example that I provided. The actual df has over 900,000 rows, and the reason I need them removed as it goes is because removing the previous rows that don't meet the criteria will accurately reflect that those values are no longer in "column_A" or "Column_B," whereas if they aren't removed a value of 410 will still appear to have a match since it still exists in the rows above.

Comment: Yes it still isn't clear. You don't need to show 900000 rows for that, just provide a small minimal example that explains what you need. I am not sure why 410 needs to be removed as you say on elements of A that don't match in B needs to be deleted.